# Java Animated transparent splash screen

Tags: java, transparency, splash-screen, animated-gif

I'd like to make a splash screen with an animated gif. My animated gif has a transparent background so I'd like to display only the visible part of my gif as a splash screen.
First of all, I must specify that I'm using Matlab so it is not possible (or I haven't found how) to override components/functions.
Here my sample code :

```
 win = javax.swing.JWindow;
 jl = javax.swing.JLabel(javax.swing.ImageIcon('C:\Users\ME\Documents\loader512-.gif'));
 win.getContentPane.add(jl);
 win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
 win.pack;
 %% set the splash image to the center of the screen
 screenSize = win.getToolkit.getScreenSize;
 screenHeight = screenSize.height;
 screenWidth = screenSize.width;
 % get the actual splashImage size
 imgHeight = 512;
 imgWidth = 512;
 win.setLocation((screenWidth-imgWidth)/2,(screenHeight-imgHeight)/2);   
 win.show
```

It works very well shwing the image, however its background is ether white or gray depending on the transparency of the window.
I also tried to play with the background of the JLabel without success.

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that every given window has a particular defined shape. Without changing the shape every Window object has a rectangular canvas in which it draws upon. The transparency only applies if you draw a object behind your GIF image. If transparency is enabled the renderer merely draws the background colour (which is normally black or white or some light gray) if nothing else is present.

Since the release of Java 7 a new method called setShape(Shape); appeared for Window objects. If your animated GIF has a fixed transparency "zone" I advise creating a custom java.awt.Shape object in which you pass to the win object via set shape.

Example:

```
win = javax.swing.JWindow;
jl = javax.swing.JLabel(javax.swing.ImageIcon('C:\Users\ME\Documents\loader512-.gif'));
win.getContentPane.add(jl);
Shape S = createCustomShape(); //Create your shape
win.setShape(S);
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
//{rest of code...}
```

If the animated GIF has a changing transparency background, you must create a complex implementation in which the Shape object updates on a frame by frame basis in response to the GIF. In my opinion, if this is the case, I wouldn't bother. :)

Read more on the Shape object [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html).

N.B. The Shape "object" is actually a interface, either use one of the implementing subclasses or create your own.

Comment: Thanks ! but the setShape is apparently not recognized to be part of the class javax.swing.JWindow (I run Java 8)

Comment: I've just realize that Matlab uses Java 6 and it is tricky to update to Java 7, as it uses a JVM and that there are some issues/bug related to Java 7 in Matlab.

Comment: @G_A Well... This may not be ideal... but there is this class called AWTUtilities with a static setShape(Window, Shape); method that does the same thing. Check out the last paragraph of this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html). This will only work for java 6 and may have problems with java 7... Its a very sneaky little class :)

Comment: Well, I know this site, and indeed, I found a way to shape my window with a circular shape that fit my gif image. It is better but not perfect. Regarding the site you mention, the problem is that if I set a window as transparent, its content is transparent too ! But I want my image to be shown...

Comment: @G_A Well I wasn't going to mention the transparency thing because like you found out, it turns the whole Window transparent. When you mean "It's not perfect" do you mean the implementation being ugly (code-wise) or do you mean the actual splash screen looks ugly (with the setShape() method)?

Comment: It's not perfect because the window is now circular as the gif image, but the center and some parts of the image that should be transparent are still displayed with a white background and I can't make it transparent.

Comment: @G_A Oh... I'm sorry it didn't turn out the way you wanted. I was under the impression that any shape can be made with the Shape interface (including ones with holes in the middle). If platform-dependableness is not a concern, you could write a "splash program" in native code (which definitely will provide support for window shape transparency) and invoke it in java (via Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder) for the duration of the loading. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The goal of my "splash screen" is not for a "splash screen" but just to display an ajax animated gif while a program is executing. As I do not want it to be displayed in the main GUI I wanted it to overlay the main window with transparency. But any way it is not crutial neither very important, just to be fency and exportable to others programs I made.

Comment: @G_A Okay then... I kinda knew I was taking things too far... lol... Good luck with the rest of your program!